# why does anaconda use Apple gcc?

Tags: gcc, anaconda

I installed Anaconda python 3.52.

I installed gcc with

```
brew install gcc
```

This results in gcc-6 symlinked in /usr/local/bin

My PATH has /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin

Issuing python in terminal gives

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Why does anaconda use the 'old' gcc? 
Should I create this symlink in /usr/local/bin

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That information line is not showing you what Python is going to use as a compiler, it is showing what compiler the Python interpreter itself was built with.

We build it with this compiler for maximal compatibility with old versions of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

As you may see `Anaconda` is using `Clang` and not `GCC`
Seems you are working on `MacOS` where is `Clang` is default compiler.

First of all : Try to update your `Xcode`/`Clang` you are using pretty old version (based on these logs)

Also you may try to change path in your `PATH`

Comment: Since Gcc-6 is in /usr/local/bin and that directory comes first in my PATH, why doesn't anaconda pick that one?

Comment: From this http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#compiler-osx  you can see that theano can be configured to use other compilers as well. When I use scikit_ learn I would like anaconda to use gcc, not clang

Comment: have you tried to follow the instrucitons :

If you still want to use g++ you can do so by setting its full path in the theano config flag gxx. Note that any bug reports on Mac using g++ will be ignored unless it can be reproduced with clang.

Comment: except I am not using theano. I am using tensorflow and it wants gcc. In general, whenever I start anaconda python it says [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin I am just trying to figure out why anaconda defaults to clang